# Вывод формы, но с разным содержанием

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня на сайте есть 4 кнопки, они выводят одну и тужу форму, но в зависимости от нажатой определенной кнопки, форма выводит разные данные. Как это можно реализовать?

```
<a class="myLinkModal" href="#">Click me 1</a>
<a class="myLinkModal_2" href="#">Click me 2</a>
<a class="myLinkModal_3" href="#">Click me 3</a>
<a class="myLinkModal_4" href="#">Click me 4</a>

    <div id="myModal">
        <h5 class="warning-text">Ссылка не доступна</h5>
        <p>На данный момент, ссылка не доступна, она будет доступна в 27 августа в 12:00</p>
        <span id="myModal__close" class="close">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 329.26933 329" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="m194.800781 164.769531 128.210938-128.214843c8.34375-8.339844 8.34375-21.824219 0-30.164063-8.339844-8.339844-21.824219-8.339844-30.164063 0l-128.214844 128.214844-128.210937-128.214844c-8.34375-8.339844-21.824219-8.339844-30.164063 0-8.34375 8.339844-8.34375 21.824219 0 30.164063l128.210938 128.214843-128.210938 128.214844c-8.34375 8.339844-8.34375 21.824219 0 30.164063 4.15625 4.160156 9.621094 6.25 15.082032 6.25 5.460937 0 10.921875-2.089844 15.082031-6.25l128.210937-128.214844 128.214844 128.214844c4.160156 4.160156 9.621094 6.25 15.082032 6.25 5.460937 0 10.921874-2.089844 15.082031-6.25 8.34375-8.339844 8.34375-21.824219 0-30.164063zm0 0" />
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="myOverlay"></div>
    <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a.myLinkModal').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#myOverlay').fadeIn(297, function () {
                    $('#myModal')
                        .css('display', 'block')
                        .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 198);
                });
            });

            $('#myModal__close, #myOverlay').click(function () {
                $('#myModal').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 198,
                    function () {
                        $(this).css('display', 'none');
                        $('#myOverlay').fadeOut(297);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или то как написано у вас `$('a.myLinkModal').click(function (event) {` сработает только для первой кнопки?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
exampleModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  // Button that triggered the modal
  var button = event.relatedTarget
  // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
  var recipient = button.getAttribute('data-bs-whatever')
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
  // and then do the updating in a callback.
  //
  // Update the modal's content.
  var modalTitle = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-title')
  var modalBodyInput = exampleModal.querySelector('.modal-body input')

  modalTitle.textContent = 'New message to ' + recipient
  modalBodyInput.value = recipient
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@fat">Open modal for @fat</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" data-bs-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```